# Ubuntu 19.10 won't poweroff

Tags: boot, grub2, shutdown

Using Acer Aspire E 17 [ ES1-711 ]
Fresh install ubuntu 19.10, and when I try to power-off or reboot, it halts after all on-screen things/massages and stay like that until manual press power-off button.

I google the problem and find that add **acpi=force** in grub "GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=force" or just
"GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="acpi=force"
for me didnt fix problem.

Is it possible due to some BIOS issues or something? If anyone can share some words of wisdom well be nice =)

Comment: Aaa... my bad. is 19.10. Ill fix in post =(
mea culpa...

Comment: Now I'm happy with this version and works nicely on my main laptop. just kinda wish to fix this =\

Comment: Until you power off?   Do sysrq keys not work?  (ie. clues that the kernel itself has shutdown and everything OS wise has stopped, and it was only power off or reboot that failed?)  Have you tried to reboot/shutdown from the 'stuck' point via sysrq keys?  Does it shutdown or reboot via command?

Comment: VIA Terminal or GUI it happens that halt. Ubuntu runs all things to poweroff and when come to end, the screen goes black and stays there and nothing works except manual power off button.

Comment: So the OS is actually off, ie. sysrq key combinations asking kernel to reboot don't do anything, sysrq keys to power off don't do anything..  After power off do you see `fsck` messages?  (ie. shutdown had not completed when you powered off thus `fsck` was triggered).  If you don't know sysrq keys, do search (magic sysrq; wikipedia article is easier than ubuntu one I think, alt+sysrq REISUB for example to cleanly shutdown OS + reboot)

Comment: Tell me the output of `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and the make/model of your computer.

Comment: Fixed it. Sorry for the delay. Work, work, work.
Updated BIOS and acpi=force is in grub file and just one update-grub fixed all. now working. =)